# How to download cross-platform wheels via pip?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm accustomed to pre-downloading packages using Pip, then copying them over to a target machine for deployment. With the newly introduced Python Wheels, I'm forced to "pip ... --no-use-wheel", as some of the downloaded packages are platform specific (I'm developing on OSX and deploying to Debian) and will not install on the target machine. Is there a way to download Wheels for target platforms (or platform independent)?

Comment: I edited your question's title as I think `cross-platform` (reminiscent of `cross-compilation` explains better what you are trying to achieve: creating a binary package on a platform A for a different platform B (as opposed to the original title that suggested creating a "universal" package instead, which - BTW - may not be possible if the package has compiled code in it).

Answer (score 37):

The `pip download` command now has the `--platform` argument, which you can use to specify the desired platform:

```
pip download --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: lxml
```

- the `--platform=manylinux1_x86_64` option indicates that you want wheels for this specific platform. `manylinux1_x86_64` means roughly "compatible with most distributions and with an intel CPU architecture". [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672621/what-are-the-valid-values-for-platform-abi-and-implementation-for-pip-do/49673284) links to some PEPs that describe which platforms exist and what OS/CPU they are compatible with.
- the `--only-binary=:all:` forces the use of binary distribution packages (ie. wheels, as opposed to sdist "source distribution packages") for ":all:" the things that will be installed in this command. Instead of `:all:`, one can pass a comma-separated list of specific distribution packages; see `pip install --help` for more info.

Note: I use the term "distribution package" to avoid confusion with the other kind of "package" (the ones one can `import` in a python script).

Edit: manylinux1 is [EOL since 1 January 2022](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux#manylinux1-centos-5-based---eol). Use an upgraded source - check manylinux's [README.md](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux).

Comment: Why there is no matching distribution for some packages? Such as `pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 tornado`. How can I download those packages?

Comment: @SiminJie not all the packages have all distributions available as wheels, but I'm sure the package maintainer would accept a contribution to address that ;-)

Comment: whats the individual options for? (i want to learn something from this entry.)

Comment: Additional tip: If you get an error "Can not use any platform or abi specific options unless installing via '--target'",  mention the taget folder.

For example, i was working on windows with venv.  This is how I installed pillow for linux.

´pip install --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --target=C:\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages Pillow´

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve that is IMO to use a custom script.

You can access the whole of the PyPI index via the [simple](https://pypi.python.org/simple) interface, if the package of interest offers one or more wheels, they will be listed at the same address + `/<package-name>`.

For example: if you were to install `setuptools` all wheels would be listed at: https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/

In your script, remember to implement the recommended tag priority as specified by [PEP-425](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#id1).  Essentially that boils down to download the most specific (as opposed to the most general) version of the package as this normally translate into performance advantages, with for example C extensions replacing pure python implementations of some algorithm.