# pip doesn't download simplegeneric package

Tags: python, pip

I'm installing ipykernel on a python 3.6 fresh install on a windows machine which doesn't have access to the internet.

On a linux machine with online access I type:

```
pip download --python-version='36' --implementation='cp' --platform='win_amd64' --only-binary=:all: ipykernel
```

It downloads the following packages:

```
ipykernel p3-none-any.whl
ipython p3-none-any.whl
jupyter_client p2.p3-none-any.whl
traitlets p2.p3-none-any.whl
tornado tar.gz
Pygments p2.p3-none-any.whl
pickleshare p2.p3-none-any.whl
prompt_toolkit p3-none-any.whl
pexpect p2.p3-none-any.whl
```

But then it fails to download `simplegeneric`:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipy
 thon> =4.0.0->ipykernel) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykerne
 l)
```

On [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) I can see that there is no wheel for `simplegeneric`, just the zip file.

How can I change pip command above so that it downloads `simplegeneric`, the zip file? Is it through the `--only-binary=:all:` flag?

On [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097168/how-to-download-cross-platform-wheels-via-pip%22this%20post%22) there's a comment (to the first answer) from Simin Jie  that touches this issue. Also, the same post, second answer, mac suggests a script which I believe could do the trick. But I was looking for a simple method. Is there?