# What are the valid values for --platform, --abi, and --implementation for pip download?

Tags: python, pip

[pip download](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) has several flags that I would like to play with `--platform`, `--abi`, and `--implementation`.

Where can I find the complete list of valid values for these flags?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there is one definitive list. You have to collect it from different sources. Start with PEP 425: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/

python tag: ‘py27’, ‘cp33’

abi tag: ‘cp32dmu’, ‘none’

platform tag: ‘linux_x86_64’, ‘any’

`--implementation`:

```
cp: CPython
ip: IronPython
pp: PyPy
jy: Jython
```

`--platform`:

```
win32
linux_i386
linux_x86_64
```

Comment: That contains some of the information, but not all. There are extensions like https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/ ... I am looking for the complete list.

Comment: You're not really saying anything what the different `--implementation` options mean or what they do.

Comment: One of the most important `--platform` tags these days, missing from the original 2012 PEP is `manylinux1_x86_64`. I also see `manylinux1_i686`. There were the `--abi` tags `cp27m` and `cp27mu` for python 2 to distinguish between ucs2 and ucs4 unicode build flags. Those are no longer relevant in python 3 though. Use the new `pip debug` feature added in v19.2 to see more tag related info. Relevant github [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6121).

Comment: After I skimmed through in the link that @ericg provided and some trial and error, I was able to grab .whl files for Windows using a macOS computer.
By entering `python -m pip download -r requirements.txt -d ../packages --platform win32 --only-binary=:all:`, I got all the files I needed for Windows :)
Thanks for the leads guys!

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to the PC (or similar platform) for which you need to download the package, per the [documentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0425/#platform-tag), the following function can be called to get the explicit platform name.

```
distutils.util.get_platform()
```

> The platform tag is simply `distutils.util.get_platform()` with all hyphens - and periods . replaced with underscore _.

#### Update:

As `distutils` is (being) deprecated, the same can be retrieved from `sysconfig`, as:

```
sysconfig.get_platform()
```

---

In our case, we have offline PCs (which *must* remain offline); so this approach works perfectly to ensure we download the correct platform for those PCs.

Answer (score 6):

If you are only downloading a single package, you could go to https://pypi.org and search for what's available.

E.g. for `orjson` https://pypi.org/project/orjson/3.8.2/#files, you can see there's things like:

- win_amd64
- manylinux_2_28_x86_64
- manylinux_2_28_aarch64
- manylinux_2_17_x86_64
- manylinux2014_x86_64
- manylinux_2_17_armv7l
- manylinux2014_armv7l
- manylinux_2_17_aarch64
- manylinux2014_aarch64
- macosx_10_9_x86_64
- macosx_11_0_arm64
- macosx_10_9_universal2
- macosx_10_7_x86_64

---

If you're curious what manylinux means, refer to this: https://github.com/pypa/manylinux

The `manylinux_x_y` refers to glibc versions, observed when you run `ldd --version` in your shell. glibc is backwards compatible, so pick a version equal to or below your current glibc version.