# how to pip download with --enable-unicode=ucs4?

Tags: pip

I want to download lxml for package in local.

Local env: MacOS

CMD:

```
pip download \
--only-binary=:all: \
--platform manylinux1_x86_64 \
--python-version 27 \
--implementation cp \
lxml==4.3.1
```

it downloads lxml-4.3.1-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

but I want lxml-4.3.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.

cp27m vs cp27mu

how to specify download with --enable-unicode=ucs4?

Answer (score 4):

It's [`--abi`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49673284/7976758):

```
pip download \
--only-binary=:all: \
--platform manylinux1_x86_64 \
--python-version 27 \
--implementation cp \
--abi cp27mu \
lxml==4.3.1
```

It works now!